# Elasticsearch cluster leaving shards unassigned

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-curator

We're running an elasticsearch cluster for logging, indexing logs from multiple locations using logstash.  We recently added two additional nodes for additional capacity whilst we await further hardware for the cluster's expansion.  Ultimately we aim to have 2 nodes for "realtime" data running on SSDs to provide fast access to recent data, and ageing the data over to HDDs for older indicies.  The new nodes we put in had a lot less memory than the existing boxes (700GB vs 5TB), but given this will be similar to the situation we'd have when we implemented SSDs, I didn't forsee it being much of a problem.

As a first attempt, I threw the nodes into the cluster trusting the new Disk spaced based allocation rules would mean they wouldn't instantly get filled up. This unfortunately wasn't the case, I awoke to find the cluster had merrily reallocated shards onto the new nodes, in excess of 99%. After some jigging of settings I managed to remove all data from these nodes and return the cluster to it's previous state (all shards assigned, cluster state green).

As a next approach I tried to implement index/node tagging similar to my plans for when we implement SSDs.  This left us with the following configuration:

- Node 1 - 5TB, tags: realtime, archive
- Node 2 - 5TB, tags: realtime, archive
- Node 3 - 5TB, tags: realtime, archive
- Node 4 - 700GB, tags: realtime
- Node 5 - 700GB, tags: realtime

(all nodes running elasticsearch 1.3.1 and oracle java 7 u55)

Using curator I then tagged indicies older than 10days as "archive" and more recent ones "realtime".  This in the background sets the index shard allocation "Require". Which my understanding is it will require the node to have the tag, but not ONLY that tag.

Unfortunately this doesn't appeared to have had the desired effect.  Most worryingly, no indices tagged as archive are allocating their replica shards, leaving 295 unassigned shards.  Additionally the realtime tagged indicies are only using nodes 4, 5 and oddly 3.  Node 3 has no shards except the very latest index and some kibana-int shards.

If I remove the tags and use exclude._ip to pull shards off the new nodes, I can (slowly) return the cluster to green, as this is the approach I took when the new nodes had filled up completely, but I'd really like to get this setup sorted so I can have confidence the SSD configuration will work when the new kit arrives.

I have attempted to enable: cluster.routing.allocation.allow_rebalance to always, on the theory the cluster wasn't rebalancing due to the unassigned replicas.
I've also tried: cluster.routing.allocation.enable to all, but again, this has had no discernable impact.

Have I done something obviously wrong? Or is there disagnostics of some sort I could use? I've been visualising the allocation of shards using Elasticsearch Head plugin.

Any assistance would be appreciated, hopefully it's just a stupid mistake that I can fix easily!

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

This probably doesn't fully answer your question, but seeing as I was looking at these docs this morning:

http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/index-modules-allocation.html#disk
You should be able to set watermarks on disk usage in your version to avoid this reoccurring.

For (manual) monitoring of clusters I quite like
https://github.com/lmenezes/elasticsearch-kopf

Currently watching my cluster sort out it's shards again (so slow) after a similar problem, but I'm still running an ancient version.